# Changing global variable using function with parameters Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change value of global variable within a function with parameters name,value.
All examples that ive read was with no parameter function.
Example

```
var one = 100;
var change = function(name,value){
// name is the name of the global variable
//value is the new value
};

change(one,300);
```

Comment: I assume `change(one,300);` should be `change("one",300);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. When you pass it as a parameter, pass as string, not the variable.

```
var one = 100;
var change = function(name, value) {
    window[name] = value;
};

change('one', 300);
console.log(one);
```

Answer (score 0):

All global variable are set on window object. so you can try the following .

```
window[name] = value;
```